# Inheritance, child class changing a protected field from Parent Class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, protected

I am currently picking up C# and I have issue on understanding inheritance.
Here's my Code:

Here's the Parent Class:

```
class Member
    {
        protected int annualFee; // protected field =only accessible within the same class in which it is declared and any class derived from it
        private string name; // private field = can be accesed of the same class or struct
        private int memberId;
        private int memberSince;


        // writing ToString() method to display the values of the four fields
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\nName: " + name + "\nMember ID: " + memberId + "\nMember Since: " + memberSince + "\nTotal Annual Fee: " + annualFee;
        }

        // adding two constructors to the member class
        public Member()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Constructor with no parameter");
        }

        public Member(string pName, int pMemberID, int pMemberSince)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Constructor with 3 parameters");
            name = pName;
            memberId = pMemberID;
            memberSince = pMemberSince;

            Console.WriteLine("Parent Constructor:" + name + ", " + memberId + ", " + memberSince);
        }
    }
```

Here's the Child Class:

```
    class VIPMember : Member
    { 
    
        public VIPMember(string name, int memberId, int memberSince) : base (name, memberId, memberSince)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child constructor with 3 paramemters");
        }

        public void CalculateAnnualFee()
        {
            annualFee = 1200 * 2 + 12 * 30; //ans = 2760
        }

        public int annualFee = 120000; // field inherit from parent class, will overwrite annual fee in CalculateAnnualfee() method
    }
```

Created instance of child class and calling the constructor and method.

```
class ClassDemo
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VIPMember myChildMember2 = new VIPMember("Andy", 2, 2011);
            myChildMember2.CalculateAnnualFee(); // method from child class VIPMember
            Console.WriteLine(myChildMember2.ToString()); // method inherit from parent class Member
            Console.WriteLine("Field from VIPMember (protected to public) class: " + myChildMember2.annualFee);

        }
    }
```

Answer:

```
Parent Constructor with 3 parameters
Parent Constructor:Andy, 2, 2011
Child constructor with 3 paramemters

Name: Andy
Member ID: 2
Member Since: 2011
Total Annual Fee: 0
Field from VIPMember (protected to public) class: 2760
```

I added the public int annualFee = 120000 field on purpose to try out. However, the output is not what I expected. I was expecting that:

```
Total Annual Fee: 2760
Field from VIPMember (protected to public) class: 12000
```

Can someone explain the logic behind?

Thank you.

Comment: You are hiding the field of the parent in the child. Don't declare it again in the child. Just use it. If you want to give it a default value, do so in the child ctor.

Comment: Btw.: I wouldn't have the Member or any of its children know how to calculate their fees. It's none of their business. I'd probably also not reflect membership status through the type system.

Comment: Also relevant: [Are there any legitimate use cases for protected visibility?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/436521/209774)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you defined `public int annualFee` in `VIPMember` you ***shadowed*** the `protected int annualFee` in `Member`. You effectively created a brand new field with the same name and made it that you only saw `annualFee` from the class that defined it. The compiler should have given you a warning that you were doing so.

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();
    Console.WriteLine(b.x);
    b.x = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(b.x);
    A a = b;
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
    a.x = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
}

public class A
{
    public int x = 1;
}

public class B : A
{
    public int x = 2;
}
```

You get:

```
2
3
1
4
```

But had I not shadowed `x` then I would write the code this way:

```
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();
    Console.WriteLine(b.x);
    b.x = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(b.x);
    A a = b;
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
    a.x = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
    Console.WriteLine(b.x);
}

public class A
{
    public int x = 1;
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        this.x = 2;
    }
}
```

Note that I needed to update `x` in the constructor of `B`.

To rewrite your code, you should have done this:

```
class VIPMember : Member
{
    public VIPMember(string name, int memberId, int memberSince) : base(name, memberId, memberSince)
    {
        this.annualFee = 120000;
        Console.WriteLine("Child constructor with 3 paramemters");
    }

    public void CalculateAnnualFee()
    {
        this.annualFee = 1200 * 2 + 12 * 30; //ans = 2760
    }
}
```

Then it works as you expect.